# Publish Rstudio Shiny App in intranet

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to build a Rstudio/Shiny App and post it in our intranet so that everyone else in our office could see it. I am a windows guy, and the instructions online about how to setup a shiny server within Linux environment is a bit difficult for me. Is there an easy way that I can could accomplish this goal without messing up with Linux. Even if I have to do so, is there an easy way to just have my webpage available to people within our company, not everyone on the internet. Thanks!

Comment: Shiny server requires linux. If you can't get a linux machine to host, your options are either to install Linux on Windows via a virtual machine or rent an Amazon Webservices EC2 instance. I've done both of these options and they're fairly straight forward. I can post the steps I followed tomorrow morning.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde, thanks. Looking forward to your post. I am now trying to install VMware on my windows machine.

Comment: if everyone has a copy of R on their machine then they can run your shiny app locally, no server required. But then nothing is shared. Change your app, you need to redistribute it (which might just mean putting it on a shared drive/private "dropbox" account).

Comment: Or put it on a (pricate) github/bitbucket account, and have it pulled off to reload. `devtools` make the process quite smooth.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde did you happen to have those steps posted anywhere?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you don't need shiny server for this, you just need to run an R instance with shiny

http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#ui-and-server

http://shiny.rstudio.com/

shiny automatically runs it at local host...
you need to change it to your own ip if you want your colleges be able to access it..

```
ip="192.168.178.10" # change this!
runApp("../microplate",host=ip) # change microplate to the name of your shiny package/app
```

Comment: From the shiny server page: "While the Shiny package itself includes a basic web server, it's only designed to serve one application at a time."

Comment: this is true, it will run in the R console on the foreground, launch multiple r consoles to get around this...

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me. Tried running on my IP (or on my computer_name,). How does the following phrase from the official documentation fit in with your answer? "To allow other clients to connect, use the value "0.0.0.0" instead (which was the value that was hard-coded into Shiny in 0.8.0 and earlier)". Just to be clear, neither work. Firewall issues or so?

Comment: can be many things... try to ping the computer using its ip-address

Comment: I had the same question and this question almost got my problem solved. However, when I enter the host-port combination, e.g. 192.168.178.10:8100, on another computer's web browser in the same local network, there is no connection.

Answer (score 2):

RStudio also has a hosted Shiny option that is currently in Alpha.  You can sign up here https://www.shinyapps.io/admin/#/signup

With hosted Shiny the intention is to let developers focus on building applications while RStudio will worry about managing servers, monitoring performance, and ensuring uptime.

Answer (score 2):

I am sharing apps using the following:

If your ui and server are in the same R file:
runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server), host="0.0.0.0", port=1234)

If you have an ui.R and a server.R files in the "shinyapp" folder:
runApp("C:/shinyapp", host="0.0.0.0", port=1234)

After, I send my IP (you can get your IP from the terminal using `ipconfig`) followed by the port that I set up as an hyperlink. Assuming that my IP is 192.168.178.10, I will send:

http://192.168.178.10:1234

[Monitoring a shiny app shared in my internal network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50396350/monitoring-a-shiny-app-shared-in-my-internal-network)