# Run shiny server through Rstudio

Tags: r, shiny-server, rstudio-server

I have shiny servers running on ubuntu for some time, but I can`t make it work on debian, I found some tutorials on google, like this

http://mars.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/mediawiki/sk/index.php/Shiny

but none of them worked for me. In this same server my Rsudio server works and I can log in and run a shiny app in the browser, is there a way to share the web link to run shiny server through Rstudio?

Answer (score 0):

You can distribute your shiny app on https://www.shinyapps.io/ and share it with others.

If you will really want to host your app with Rstudio-server, maybe this answer is helpful:

[Publish Rstudio Shiny App in intranet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750096/publish-rstudio-shiny-app-in-intranet)

Comment: I think the point is to run it on user's own infrastructure, not on a 3rd party system...

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Ping, but it did not work 'Error in startPipeServer(port, mask, handlerManager$createHttpuvApp()) :'