# Monitoring a shiny app shared in my internal network

Tags: r, shiny, network-programming, lan

Is there any way to keep track of users accessing my shiny app that is shared internally, through:

```
runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server), host="0.0.0.0", port=1234)
```

Also, I was wondering if one can add semaphores to restrict the access of some IPs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to put your app in a Docker container, then you can associate a log for that, even can add user and password checking as any other application.

Also if you want the best performance and another level of an enterprise solution, you can use shiny proxy, it is an opensource option for your own shiny server and cloud fancy way

Comment: Your post help me, then asking did you solve the monitoring with de docker option? maybe can help or work together